# Removing/ clearing selected option displayed in datalist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-datalist

I am using two methods of selection in my page, one, using a datalist and another, using a dropdown. Say, I select an option from the datalist. The selected value will be displayed in its textbox like in the following image:

[sample image of datalist after selection of option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi7wz.png)

Now, when I select a value from the dropdown, I am trying to clear/remove the selection made previously using the datalist . i.e., I would simply like to display an empty space instead of the selected option in the text box of datalist (like it was, before selecting any value from the datalist options).

I have tried using      `$('#selectCar').val(" ");`.
But this clears all the options from the datalist too. Instead, I would only like the displayed text changed/deleted.
Any suggestions on how this can be done is much appreciated!

Sample datalist:

```
<body> 
   <label>Your Cars Name: </label> 
   <input type="text" id="selectCar" list="cars"> 
   <datalist id="cars"> 
       <option value="BMW"/> 
       <option value="Bentley"/> 
       <option value="Mercedes"/> 
       <option value="Audi"/> 
       <option value="Volkswagen"/> 
   </datalist> 
</body>
```

I have tried using a *placeholder* too. But after an option in the datalist has been selected, I was unable to reset it to the value of placeholder when a value from the dropdown is selected. If this is possible, please let me know how it can be done too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to work for me, probably because I am using a datalist.. Also, I have another drop down list (select list) in the same page which also uses <option> and this method does not select the list using id or other such attributes. Thank you for your suggestion.. Although any improvement on that answer which would help my use case is much appreciated!

Comment: I have tried one of the solutions suggested by you in the link  **$("select").val([]);**  . And it does seem to work when I replace "select" with "#selectCar" (referring to the id in my use case). Thank you so much! :)